# Reading value at an address

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that reads the value at a certain address.
I have this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int *address;
    address =   (int*)0x00000021;
    cout << *address;
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives a read violation error. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this?

Comment: Where did you get the address from? Are you running in virtual mode (I suspect …)? Is the program linked in kernel mode (presumably not …)?

Comment: Because I want to learn more about how computers work

Comment: @User:  Ah, fair enough.  Well, you just learned something:  You can't just read & write to arbitrary memory like we could in the old days.  Now stuff is "protected".  You can only read & write memory you have permissions for.

Comment: But how does OlyDbg read out of virtual memory?

Comment: it hooks itself before the memory manager of your OS..

Comment: In our hardware class we looked at the LC2 where the whole memory was exposed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use a pointer that points to an actual object.

If you don't have an object at address `0x00000021`, this won't work.

If you want to create an object on the free store (the heap), you need to do so using `new`:

```
int* address = new int;
*address = 42;
cout << *address;
delete address;
```

Comment: Then how can I get the value in memory, because OlyDbg can tell me what is at this address...

Comment: @user146780:  Debuggers generally use operating system-specific and environment-specific hooks to read data from a given address in a process's virtual address space or in physical memory.

Answer (score 5):

That reads the value at that address within the process's own space. You'll need to use other methods if you want to read another process's space, or physical memory.

Answer (score 3):

It's open to some question exactly what OlyDbg is showing you. 32-bit (and 64-bit) Windows uses virtual memory, which means the address you use in your program is *not* the same as the address actually sent over the bus to the memory chips. Instead, Windows (and I should add that other OSes such as Linux, MacOS, *bsd, etc., do roughly the same) sets up some tables that say (in essence) when the program uses an address in *this* range, use *that* range of physical addresses.

This mapping is done on a page-by-page basis (where each page is normally 4K bytes, though other sizes are possible). In that table, it can also mark a page as "not present" -- this is what supports paging memory to disk. When you try to read a page that's marked as not present, the CPU generates an exception. The OS then handles that exception by reading the data from the disk into a block of memory, and updating the table to say the data is present at physical address X. Along with not-present, the tables support a few other values, such as read-only, so you can read by not write some addresses.

Windows (again, like the other OSes) sets up the tables for the first part of the address space, but does NOT associate any memory with them. From the viewpoint of a user program, those addresses simply should never be used.

That gets us back to my uncertainty about what OlyDbg is giving you when you ask it to read from address 0x21. That address simply doesn't refer to any real data -- never has and never will.

What others have said is true as well: a debugger will usually use some OS functions (E.g. `ReadProcessMemory` and `WriteProcessMemory`, among others under Windows) to get access to things that you can't read or write directly. These will let you read and write memory in another process, which isn't directly accessible by a normal pointer. Neither of those would help in trying to read from address 0x21 though -- that address doesn't refer to any real memory in *any* process.

Answer (score 1):

When your program is running on an operating system that provides virtual memory (Windows, *nix, OS X) Not all addresses are backed by memory. CPU's that support virtual memory use something called [Page Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) to control which address refer to memory.  The size of an individual page is usually 4096 bytes, but that does vary and is likely to be larger in the future.

The API's that you use to query the page tables isn't part of the standard C/C++ runtime, so you will need to use operating system specific functions to know which adresses are OK to read from and which will cause you to fault.   On Windows you would use [VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366902(VS.85).aspx) to find out if a given address can be read, written, executed, or any/none of the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just read data from an arbitrary address in memory.